# What is the most efficient way to dispute an invalid collection on a credit report?

Tags: united-states, credit-score, credit-report, debt-collection

I had a surgery and a ton of medical issues. All but one thing went through insurance. The healthcare provider for that one thing went straight to collections. I contacted them, and my insurance company handled it. However that one thing put a huge dent in my FICO score. What would be the best way to get it resolved and off my record? Or is such a thing infeasible?

Answer (score 1):

You can file your dispute through the credit bureaus’ website, over the phone, or by mail. The easiest and fastest way is to do it online. Whichever route you go, you will have to provide personal information, a description of the information that needs to be corrected, and documentation to back your claim. Credit bureaus have 30 days to investigate your claim and provide you with a written resolution. If your claim is validated, they will also send you a copy of your updated credit report.

Most disputes dealing with removing inaccurate information get resolved smoothly. Make sure you follow the steps and provide all the necessary documentation to back your claim. Having a negative account removed from your credit report can give you score a boost and help you get your credit ready to buy a house in the near future. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

To remove a collection, you have to be able to prove that the debt was not yours and has been paid:

> You have rights. Ask for a validation notice, which says what you owe and to whom. After you get it, consider sending a letter saying that you don’t owe the debt. If you’re getting debt collection calls, check your free credit report at annualcreditreport.com. If a debt you don’t recognize shows up there, follow the instructions to dispute the debt. And, as always, report any problems to the FTC.

**References**

- [Bogus debts, bogus collections | Page 4 | Consumer Information](https://www.consumer.ftc.gov/blog/2016/04/bogus-debts-bogus-collections?page=3)
- [Debt Collection FAQs | Consumer Information](https://www.consumer.ftc.gov/articles/debt-collection-faqs)